# Как убирать файл ресурса android

Tags: java, android

У меня есть gif которая должна после загрузки сетаться на пустоту, конечно самое глупое это взять пустое png и сетнуть через `setBackgroundResource`, но есть ли другой способ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я бы не пытался устраивать танцы с бубном вокруг setBackgroundResoure.

Самое простое решение которое тут напрашивается, это вызвать `view.setVisibility(View.GONE);`

Если же вам по каким-то причинам необходимо оставить вашу View видимой, вы можете задать просто фон нужного вам цвета. Или вообще прозрачный.